# Rendering multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a form component, and the reference of input fields are linked to the useForm reducer with references. I have to set a initial form state after setting the input field references? I have done as below. But it is rendering thrice. How to solve this rendering issue?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const useForm = () => {

    const [ formState, setFormState ] = useState({});
    const refs = useRef({});

    const register = useCallback(( fieldArgs ) => ref => {
        if(fieldArgs) {
            const { name, validations, initialValue } = fieldArgs;
    
            refs.current[name] = ref;
        }
        console.log('Register rendered');
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Effect Rendered');
        const refsKeys = Object.keys(refs.current);
        refsKeys.forEach(refKey => {
            if(!formState[refKey]) {
                setFormState(prevState => {
                    return {
                        ...prevState,
                        [refKey]: {
                            value: '',
                            touched: false,
                            untouched: true,
                            pristine: true,
                            dirty: false
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }, [ refs ]);

    return [ register ];
}

export { useForm };
```

And the app component as below

```
const App = () => {

    const [ register ] = useFormsio();

    return(
        <form>

            <input
                type = 'email'
                placeholder = 'Enter your email'
                name = 'userEmail'
                ref = { register({ name: 'userEmail' }) } />

            <button
                type = 'submit'>
                    Submit
            </button>

        </form>
    )
}
```

[image]

How to solve this multiple rendering issue?

Comment: is the two renderings a performance problem? Sometimes react needs to repeat renders as part of their reconciliation algorithm, and their recommendation is to focus more on having cheap render functions (so rerenders are not a big deal), as skipping re-renders might cause incorrect render results.
having said that, your ref is probably null in the first render, and then it takes a value, causing the effect to fire and then causing the component that uses the hook to rerender

Comment: I have use useEffect with dependencies to set state, then its rendering thrice. If i tried useEffect with same dependencies, but without setting state in it, its rendering once. So I thought whether its a good to setState in useEffect or not?

Comment: you should always be honest and put the dependencies in the array that your effect uses to; otherwise it could lead to unexpected bugs (Whether it is now or in the future if you update your effect)

Comment: Okay! I am not able to figure out the issue with my code. Could you please help to figure out the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue in the code above is whenever refs changes you need to loop through all the fields in form and set the state.
Why don't you set the state in register method?

```
const register = useCallback(( fieldArgs ) => ref => {
        if(fieldArgs) {
            const { name, validations, initialValue } = fieldArgs;
            if(!refs.current[name] ) {
                refs.current[name] = ref;
                setFormState(prevState => {
                    return {
                        ...prevState,
                        [refKey]: {
                            value: '',
                            touched: false,
                            untouched: true,
                            pristine: true,
                            dirty: false
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        console.log('Register rendered');
    }, []);
```